# Sum corresponding elements of multiple python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

I have an arbitrary number of equal-length python dictionaries with matching sets of keys, like this:

```
{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':8, 'd':9}

{'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':7}

{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4}
...
```

How can I obtain a single dictionary with the same set of keys but with values as the sums of corresponding elements in the dictionary set? In other words, I'd want:

```
{'a':3, 'b':8, 'c':13, 'd':20}
```

Maybe there's an ugly, complicated loop structure, but is there a nicer way to do this with some kind of list/dict comprehension cleverness? Come to think of it, I'm really not sure how to make an ugly loop version, anyway..

Comment: Where do the original dictionaries exist? Are they all individually named? Or do they exist in a collection or array of dictionaries?

Comment: They are indexed by id numbers in a larger, overall dictionary. I want to be able to sum certain, variably-sized subset (e.g., the ones with keys 1, 5, 34, and 67).

Comment: You can still use @TimPeters' answer with your ID numbers if you create a list of dictionaries like `DList = [ d[1],d[5],d[34],d[67] ]` (And there are ways to generate that list programmatically if you search elsewhere on the site about making a list from specified elements...)

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but will that work if I have a dictionary of dictionaries? Something like: `for id_num in cluster: 
                                      c.update(overall_dict[id_num])`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`collections.Counter()` to the rescue ;-)

```
from collections import Counter
dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':8, 'd':9},
         {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':7},
         {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4}]
c = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    c.update(d)
```

Then:

```
>>> print c
Counter({'d': 20, 'c': 13, 'b': 8, 'a': 3})
```

Or you can change it back to a dict:

```
>>> print dict(c)
{'a': 3, 'c': 13, 'b': 8, 'd': 20}
```

It doesn't matter to `Counter()` whether all the input dicts have same keys.  If you know for sure that they do, you could try ridiculous ;-) one-liners like this:

```
d = {k: v for k in dicts[0] for v in [sum(d[k] for d in dicts)]}
```

`Counter()` is clearer, faster, and more flexible.  To be fair, though, this slightly less ridiculous one-liner is less ridiculous:

```
d = {k: sum(d[k] for d in dicts) for k in dicts[0]}
```

Comment: Nice. I like your "less ridiculous" version, but it might be clearer if you use something besides `d` for the destination dictionary...

Comment: @beroe, but that would make it even less ridiculous! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I thought that was the [recursive] point... :^)

Answer (score 6):

If you simply want to use `dict` only, you can use this

```
dicts = [{'a':0, 'b':4, 'c':8, 'd':9},
         {'a':0, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':7},
         {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4}]

result = {}
for myDict in dicts:
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        result.setdefault(key, 0)
        result[key] += value
print result
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 13, 'b': 8, 'd': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using sentinel value of `sum` as a `Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':8, 'd':9},
         {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':7},
         {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4}]
>>> dict(sum(map(Counter, dicts), start=Counter()))
{'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 13, 'd': 20}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative using *dictionary comprehension* with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Here, I am creating a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of keys from all the three dicts. Then I am iterating over this set inside *dictionary comprehension* to get the sum of *values* per *key*.

```
from itertools import chain

my_dicts = [
    {'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':8, 'd':9},
    {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':7},
    {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':3, 'd':4}
]
    
new_dict = {k: sum(dd.get(k, 0) for dd in my_dicts) for k in set(chain.from_iterable(d.keys() for d in my_dicts))}

# where `new_dict` will hold:
#   {
#      'a': 3,  
#      'b': 8,
#      'c': 13,
#      'd': 20
#   }
```